# Generate a table in the UI Designer from a local variable and from business variable

Tags: database-connection, ui-design, bonita

I have a connector that selects data from an external database in Bonitasoft, I was able to assign the result of this select to a process variable and display the contents of that variable in the UI Designer in an Input type field, however I need to display this in a table, as I configure This in the UI Designer to display the contents of my process variable in a table, if possible show the step by step thank you. Another thing as I can also pass the contents of my connector to a business variable and then display in UI Designer also if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I want to draw your attention that using business or process variables to store data already stored in an external database will lead to duplication.
Recommended solution would be to use a REST API extension (such as [REST API SQL data source](https://github.com/Bonitasoft-Community/rest-api-sql-data-source)) to query the data from the external database and use this REST API extension in the forms.

Now if you are ok with duplication of data you can refer to an [example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d48nxrl9wrdlne0/DemoExternalDatabaseBadDiagram-1.0.bos?dl=0) I create that demonstrate how to set process and business data with PostgreSQL connector output and then display the variables in form table widgets.

I highly recommend to use business variable and if possible consider migrating the data from the external database to the business data database.